# Execute a function ever 60 seconds

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I want to execute a function every 60 seconds in C#. I could use the Timer class like so:

```
timer1 = new Timer();
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
timer1.Interval = 60 * 1000; // in miliseconds
timer1.Start();
```

Question is I have a long running process. Occasionally it make take several minutes. Is there a way to make the timer smart so if the function is already being executed then it should skip that cycle and come back 60 seconds later and if again it is in execution then again skip and come back 60 seconds later.

Comment: No. This can only be done with the [PeriodicTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-6.0) class introduced in .NET 6

Comment: in your eventhandler set a flag that it's already executed, and set it to false when that long-running operation is done.

Comment: you can make the function smart. set a variable and check if another process is already running this function. be careful of the scope of this variable

Comment: You can stop timer at the beginning of `timer1_Tick`, then restart it at the end (inside `finally` block).

Comment: You can put that "long-running task" inside an infinite loop with a 60-second `Thread.Sleep` (or `Task.Delay`), maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to have a class member variable `bool` variable with value `false`.

then in click event return if its `true` at the beginning.

and then set it to `true`, so that it will tell you that its currently in execution.

then write your logic.

and then once done finally set it to `false` again.

code will look like this.

```
private bool isRunning = false;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isRunning)
    {
        return;
    }

    isRunning = true;
    
    try
    {
        ... //Do whatever you want 
    }
    finally
    {
        isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The modern and most clean way to do this is using Microsoft's new [Period Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer.waitfornexttickasync?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0):

```
var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(n));

while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
{
    //Business logic
}
```

If you need to abort such a ticker, you can pass a cancellation token to the WaitForNextTickAsync method.

Another advantage is this:

> The PeriodicTimer behaves like an auto-reset event, in that multiple ticks are coalesced into a single tick if they occur between calls to WaitForNextTickAsync(CancellationToken). Similarly, a call to Dispose() will void any tick not yet consumed. WaitForNextTickAsync(CancellationToken) may only be used by one consumer at a time, and may be used concurrently with a single call to Dispose().

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer.waitfornexttickasync?source=recommendations&view=net-7.0#remarks

---

If you need more granularity (like "always at 10 am", use something like https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos

Answer (score 1):

Use a timer, set it to 60 second

On Event:

```
try
  Stop timer
  Do logic
catch
  What ever fail recovery 
finally
  Start the timer
```

Logic is run 60 seconds after last finish.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-7.0) inside a loop: start the stopwatch, after 60 second call the function, reset the stopwatch, start the loop again.

Comment: A Stopwatch is more for *measuring* time, it cannot alert that 60 seconds have passed

Comment: You can check manually the `Elapsed` property of the stopwatch inside the loop. Actually, the question is about _measuring_ time.

Comment: But then you will need a busy-loop. OK, it can be slowed down by adding some Thread.Sleep (or Task.Delay)